# Compare two text files and print the difference

Tags: perl

Compare two different text files.

```
use List::Compare;
use POSIX qw/strftime/;
use strict;
open (CMP_LIST1, "D:\\Compare\\List1.txt") || die ("cannot open general.txt");
open (CMP_LIST2, "D:\\Compare\\List2.txt") || die ("cannot open search.txt");
undef $/;
my $cmp_list1 = <CMP_LIST1>;
my $cmp_list2 = <CMP_LIST2>;
my @cmp1_array = split /\n/, $cmp_list1;
my @cmp2_array = split /\n/, $cmp_list2;
close CMP_LIST1;
close CMP_LIST2;
my $count = scalar @cmp1_array;
for(my $i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
   &Compare($cmp1_array[$i],$cmp2_array[$i]);
}
print "over";
sub Compare {
    my ($cmp1_filename,$cmp2_filename)=@_;
    my $time = strftime('%H_%M_%S',localtime);
    open(OUT,">$time.txt");
    open (F, "$cmp1_filename")||die("$cmp1_filename File cannot open\n");
    open (S, "$cmp2_filename")||die("$cmp2_filename File cannot open\n");
    my @a=<F>;
    my @b=<S>;
    my $lcma = List::Compare->new(\@a, \@b);
    print OUT "$cmp2_filename\n", $lcma->get_complement,"\n";#extra present in the second array
    print OUT "$cmp1_filename\n", $lcma->get_unique,"\n";#extra present in the First array
    close OUT;
    sleep 1;
}
```

Compare file list, I have given as loop. But I am not getting the exact output.

Please can any one suggest for this process.

Comment: Please provide your actual code; besides that: `use strict` and `use warnings`; that will point you to a lot of errors. (You don't really have a file named `c:<TAB>est1.tst`, do you?)

Comment: Works for me. Describe what you mean with "exact output". What do the input files look like? What does the output look like on your system? If it's wrong, what do you expect it to look like? - [Please edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9533688/edit) to amend the missing info.

Comment: I have updated the code. Now could please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,I don't know why you are using `OUT` filehandle in `print` statements.
I don't think, It is required.

Also `$lcma->get_unique` will give you values only in first file/list.
And `$lcma->get_complement` will give you values only in second file/list.
For Common values in both use `$lcma->get_intersection`.

Also, you are supposed to close the filehandles at the end.

Here is a code below for your help (Note: I am considering test1 and test2 files contain list of values s)

### test1.txt

```
12345   
abcde   
00000  
33333
```

### test2.txt

```
12345   
abcde   
00999   
33322
```

### list_difference.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Compare;

open F, "<test1.txt" or die $!;
open S, "<test2.txt" or die $!;
my @a=<F>;
my @b=<S>;
my $lc = List::Compare->new(\@a, \@b);

my @intersection = $lc->get_intersection;
my @firstonly = $lc->get_unique;
my @secondonly = $lc->get_complement;


print "Common Items:\n"."@intersection"."\n";
print "Items Only in First List:\n"."@firstonly"."\n";
print "Items Only in Second List:\n"."@secondonly"."\n";

print "test1.txt \n", $lc->get_unique,"\n"; 
print "test2.txt \n", $lc->get_complement,"\n"; 

close F;
close S;
```

Please note that the items/values in the files(test1,test2) should be separated on newline and proper spacing also required.

Comment: Cool.. Didn't know about List::Compare. But the order will be "lost" right? So (foo,bar) == (bar,foo) ?